# Davinci Fusion Planar tracking, effect mask distorted size

Tags: davinci-resolve, mask, fusion

I'm having problems trying to apply a polygon mask to a planar tracking media which is UHD. My project is HD and my background image (the building) is also UHD. My tracking window and mask look like this:

[image: Fusion mask and planar tracker]

Then when I attach the polygon mask it gets scaled like this:

[image: Fusion mask and planar tracker squashed]

How can I resize the media or the mask so it fits my background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to apply the mask and background with a merge node after the original composite using the tracking data like this:

[image: Solution image]